# Is it possible to change a weapons affinity in Elden Ring without changing its skill?

Tags: elden-ring

In Elden Ring a weapons affinity (i.e. quality, keen, heavy, et cetera), which can alter a weapons scaling and damage type, is now tied to Ashes of War. The problem is that Ashes of War also change a weapons skill. This presents  a problem when I'm using a weapon with a skill I really like, but doesn't have the type of scaling I desire.

**Is there a way to alter a weapons affinity without also altering a weapons skill?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to change the affinity without changing (technically you'd need to change it though) weapon's skill.

To do this, you have to change the skill to same skill that your preferred weapon has - for example, if you want to change the Long Sword's affinity, you'd need Square Off Ashes of War, and you also need specific whetblade for the affinity that you want to have. So far, I've found these:

- *Iron Whetblade* for **Quality / Keen / Heavy**
- *Glintstone Whetblade* for **Magic / Cold**
- *Red-Hot Whetblade* for **Fire / Flame Art**
- *Black Whetblade* for **Poison / Blood / Occult**
- *Sancrified Whetblade* for **Sacred / Lightning**

I'll update this post if I find more whetblade.

Comment: By the way, feel free to edit the list's style (and of course if you find another whetblade, let me know or just suggest edit). I'm not good at styling texts... :(